# Specifying order parameter through a belongsTo table in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Let's say I've got two tables: `cities` and `countries`. The `City` model `belongsTo` a `Country`. Now, when I display lists of cities, I want them to be ordered by country name and then city name.

I tried this in my `City` model class:

```
var $order = array('Country.name' => 'asc', 'City.name' => 'asc');
```

The sort order works correctly for my index page, but I get errors in several places where the model has been asked not to load associated models. Do I have to change the order parameters when I change which tables are loaded, or is there a smarter way to do this?

For now, I think I'll make the default order definition be `City.name` and then just change it to `Country.name` and `City.name` on the index page. That way it's safe by default, and I shouldn't get unexpected errors.

**Update:** As [Rob suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489981/specifying-order-parameter-through-a-belongsto-table-in-cakephp/1492327#1492327) you can specify order parameters in the model associations. The query builder applies them like this:

1. If there is an `order` field on the main model, apply it first.
2. Walk through all the associated models in the order they appear. If the association includes an `order` parameter, add it to the end of the list.

To implement my example, I would do it like this:

```
class City extends AppModel {
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'order' => array('Country.name' => 'asc', 'City.name' => 'asc')));
}
```

One caution: if you turn off `City.recursive`, then the cities will be unsorted. However, I'm usually retrieving only one record when I've turned off recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried defining the order directly in your association? I've never needed to do this, so I can't swear it will do what you're after, but:

```
class City extends AppModel {
    $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'Order' => 'Country.name'
        )
    );
}
```

You could do something similar for your `Country` model, of course.

Comment: This works. See my update in the question for the details of how the order fields interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

this is untested, but the idea is
in the country model you can do

```
hasMany = array('City');
function beforeFind()
{
    foreach($this->hasMany as $model)
    {
        $this->order[] = $model['className'].'.'.'ASC';
    }
}
```

not worth doing IMO. ur way is fine.